# Count of items that pass QSoftFilterProxyModel

Tags: qt, qt5, qtquick2

I am trying to access the number of items that pass the filters in a `QSortFilterProxyModel` from QML. I can not find any built in functions that alleviate this.

My approach would be to give the FilterModel a property like this:

```
Q_PROPERTY(int count READ rowCount NOTIFY countChanged)
```

and connect the `countChanged` signal to the source models `dataChanged` signal. While I am confident that this would work it seems overly complicated. Is there a better method I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is sadly no better way to do it.

To make it work like that, you need do connect your `countChanged` signal to your proxy model: `rowsInserted`, `rowsRemoved`, `modelReset` and `layoutChanged` signals. That's what I did in my QML proxy model implementation : https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel/blob/d2772bd6e40ce81a07712c5c320d0ff1b709ce37/qqmlsortfilterproxymodel.cpp#L33-L36

ALternatively, I also did try as a proof of concept a non intrusive qml model helper, to expose data from a `QAbstractItemModel` in a friendly way. It works with an attached object for the model : https://github.com/oKcerG/QmlModelHelper (check the [test for the count feature](https://github.com/oKcerG/QmlModelHelper/blob/master/tests/tst_count.qml))

To query the count of a model, you'd do:

`myModel.ModelHelper.count`, it's a property, so you'll get change notifications and proper binding with it.